# How to remove EF 4.2 and reset my Visual studio

Tags: entity-framework

I installed a lot of ado.net entity framework versions and tools. one of them was this one: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26660

Now there are a lot of problems while trying to add a new entity data model, and also can't use any code generation tools such as dbcontext code generator.

What I want to know is how to remove all of these ef versions and reset my Visual studio 10.

Note, I repaired my vs, and reinstalled the SP1 but with no hope, the same errors are there.

here are 2 screen shots that may let you help me better:

installed items in my VS:
[image]

error appear after trying to add a new entity data model:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uninstallation procedure of EF June 2011 CTP is described in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx). As you see in your linked download page there is red text in instructions describing issues with CTP. That CTP should have never been installed on your main development (production) machine because it breaks existing VS functionalities. The instructions directly says that it should be installed in non-production environment (for example virtual machine).

Comment: this solved my issue, but after cleaning my registry using ccleaner, may be my special case, but at the end everything worked, thanks.